# What's the purpose of that use 'dir &@ ' as order-only-prerequisites?

Tags: makefile

Below code is part of Makefile,i confuse what the purpose of use `$$$$(dir $$$$@)` as order-only-prerequisites in **cc_template** function

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
# get .o obj files: (#files[, packet])
toobj = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)$(SLASH)$(if $(2),$(2)$(SLASH)),\
                $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(1))))

# get .d dependency files: (#files[, packet])
todep = $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(call toobj,$(1),$(2)))

# cc compile template, generate rule for dep, obj: (file, cc[, flags, dir])
define cc_template
$$(call todep,$(1),$(4)): $(1) | $$$$(dir $$$$@)
        @$(2) -I$$(dir $(1)) $(3) -MM $$< -MT "$$(patsubst %.d,%.o,$$@) $$@"> $$@
$$(call toobj,$(1),$(4)): $(1) | $$$$(dir $$$$@)
        @echo + cc $$<
        $(V)$(2) -I$$(dir $(1)) $(3) -c $$< -o $$@
ALLOBJS += $$(call toobj,$(1),$(4))
endef
```

The whole Makefile is from https://github.com/chyyuu/ucore_os_lab/blob/master/labcodes/lab1/tools/function.mk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't directly ask about the quoting I won't go through it, except to say that after all is said and done what this will do is make the target's directory into an order-only prerequisite.

So, if your target is `my/foo/bar.o` then `my/foo` will be an order-only prerequisite of that target.

This is done to ensure that the target directory exists before invoking the rule that creates an object file in it (the compiler won't create output directories for you: if they don't exist it will just fail).

Elsewhere in your makefile you should find a rule that creates directories:

```
<sometargets>:
        mkdir -p $@
.PHONY: <sometargets>
```

Comment: I think you are right,although i can't find the rule that creates directories.I only recently learn how to write Makefile.

Comment: It's there somewhere, else you'd get an error from make saying "no rule to build target..." or similar.